# Signal handling c programming

Tags: c, process, operating-system, signals

I am trying to learn signals in C programming, but I am having a hard time understanding some concepts. I have this code available and I was hoping someone could guide me through it. I'm mostly trying to understand in `main()` what is the difference between the long form and short form.

1. What does `SA_SIGINFO | SA_RESTART;` do in the long form?
2. Why do we use one handler function to initialize `action.sa_sigaction` in the long form and then use another signal handler to initialize `action.sa_handler`?

```c
#include    <errno.h>
#include    <math.h>
#include    <stdlib.h>
#include    <signal.h>
#include    <stdio.h>
#include    <unistd.h>
#include    <sys/time.h>
#include    "printBlocked.h"

// Timer demonstration of signal handling.  Timer intervals are random.

static int
bkr_random( int lo, int hi )
{
    static int  seed = 2*3*5*7*11*13*17*19+1;
    static int  prime = 2*3*5*7*11*13*17+1;
    int     value;

    value = lo + (seed>>3) % (hi-lo+1);
    seed *= prime;
    seed = seed < 0 ? -seed : seed;
    return value;
}

static void
timeout_handler( int signo, siginfo_t * info , void * p )
{
    struct itimerval    interval;

    printf( "timeout_handler() invoked.  errno is %d\n", info->si_errno );
    printBlocked( "timeout handler" );
    interval.it_interval.tv_usec = 0;               /* No repeat interval */
    interval.it_interval.tv_sec = 0;
    interval.it_value.tv_sec = 0;
    interval.it_value.tv_usec = 25000 * bkr_random( 1, 39 );    /* reset interval each time */
    setitimer( ITIMER_REAL, &interval, 0 );
}

static void
signal_handler( int signo )
{
    switch ( signo )
    {
        case SIGINT:
            printf( "Signal handler invoked.  Delivered signal is %s.\n", _sys_siglist[signo] );
            printBlocked( "signal handler" );
            exit( 0 );
            break;
        case SIGWINCH:
            system( "clear" );
            printf( "Signal handler invoked.  Window size changed.\n" );
            printBlocked( "signal handler" );
            break;
        default:
            printf( "Signal handler invoked.  unknown signal delivered is %s.\n", _sys_siglist[signo] );
            printBlocked( "signal handler" );
            break;
    }
}

int
main()
{
    struct sigaction    action;
    struct itimerval    interval;

    printf( "main() invoked in process %d.\n", getpid() );
    printBlocked( "main()" );

    action.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO | SA_RESTART;  /* asking for long form and abilty to continue normal execution */
    action.sa_sigaction = timeout_handler;      /* long form */
    sigemptyset( &action.sa_mask );         /* no additional signals blocked */
    sigaction( SIGALRM, &action, 0 );

    action.sa_flags = 0;
    action.sa_handler = signal_handler;     /* short form */
    sigemptyset( &action.sa_mask );         /* no additional signals blocked */
    sigaction( SIGINT, &action, 0 );
    sigaction( SIGWINCH, &action, 0 );

    interval.it_interval.tv_sec = 0;                /* No repeat interval */
    interval.it_interval.tv_usec = 0;
    interval.it_value.tv_usec = 25000 * bkr_random( 1, 39 );    /* initial interval */
    interval.it_value.tv_sec = 0;
    setitimer( ITIMER_REAL, &interval, 0 );

    while( pause() == -1 );             /* wait for a signal, any signal */
    printf( "Normal end.\n" );
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally, see the documentation for [`sigaction`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695299/functions/sigaction.html).

Specifically,

> *What does SA_SIGINFO | SA_RESTART; do in the long form?*

SA_SIGINFO tells the system to call the "long form" handler `sa_sigaction` rather than the "short form" handler `sa_handler`.

SA_RESTART tells the system to restart certain system calls upon return from the signal handler.  Otherwise, those calls would normally fail with errno set to EINTR.  This applies whether or not SA_SIGINFO is set.

> *Why do we use one handler function to initialize action.sa_sigaction in the long form and then use another signal handler to initialize action.sa_handler?*

`sa_sigaction` is typically used when one wants the extra `siginfo_t` information passed in.  In this case, the author of the code you show wants to know what errno was associated with the signal generation (`si_errno`).  Now, on my system, that field will always be zero in the code shown — there's no errno associated with an alarm we ourselves set, nor one delivered externally (as by the *kill(1)* command).

The other signal actions don't require that extra information, so there's no harm in using the simpler `sa_handler` interface.

(As an aside, good signal handling practice restricts the handlers to calling functions which are [async-signal-safe](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/xsh_chap02_04.html).  The code you post does not do that.)

Comment: Interesting if this `si_errno` will be ever `!= 0`. May be on Solaris? Couldn't find any docu on this one.

Comment: @flyer, I think it's typically set for "system-generated" signals, like SIGBUS.